# stringWithContentsOfUrl failing after updating to OS3.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url

I have an application which has been running happily, but since I updated to OS3.1 and updated the SDK the application is failing to log onto a remote server, passing a connection string to the stringWithContentsOfUrl function.

Before the update this was working fine, and if I copy the text string which is displayed on the NSLog statement and paste that into a browser, then I get the correct response, however, this is replying with "LOGIN_ERROR" indicating failure.

Any idea why this is now failing and how to fix it?

```
NSString* userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username_pref"];
    NSString* password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password_pref"];
    NSString* loginUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://website.com/API/login?email=%@&password=%@", userName, password];

    NSLog (@"Logging in as %@ using %@ at [%@]", userName, password, loginUrl);

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginUrl];
    NSString* loginDetails = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];

    if ([loginDetails compare:@"\"LOGIN_ERROR\""] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        DLog (@"Login Failed : LOGIN_ERROR");
        self.isLoggedIn = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        DLog (@"Login Success");
        if (userDetails) {
            [userDetails release];
        }

        NSDictionary* jsonData          = [loginDetails JSONValue];

        userDetails                     = [[[DMUserDetails alloc] init] retain];
        userDetails.id                  = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
        userDetails.api_token           = [jsonData objectForKey:@"api_token"];
        userDetails.full_name           = [jsonData objectForKey:@"full_name"];
        userDetails.mobile_number       = [jsonData objectForKey:@"mobile_number"];
        userDetails.mobile_host         = [jsonData objectForKey:@"mobile_host"];
        userDetails.email               = [jsonData objectForKey:@"email"];
        userDetails.twitter             = [jsonData objectForKey:@"twitter"];
        userDetails.jabber              = [jsonData objectForKey:@"jabber"];
        userDetails.msn                 = [jsonData objectForKey:@"msn"];
        userDetails.start_page          = [jsonData objectForKey:@"start_page"];
        userDetails.date_format         = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"date_format"] intValue];
        userDetails.time_format         = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"time_format"] intValue];
        userDetails.sort_order          = [[jsonData objectForKey:@"sort_order"] intValue];
        userDetails.timezone            = [jsonData objectForKey:@"timezone"];
        userDetails.tz_offset           = [jsonData objectForKey:@"tz_offset"];
        userDetails.premium_until       = [jsonData objectForKey:@"premium_until"];
        userDetails.default_reminder    = [jsonData objectForKey:@"default_reminder"];

        self.isLoggedIn = YES;
    }

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishLogon) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: you may want to look at web server logs, if you have a possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not my web server, so that is not possible

Comment: Code looks good to me. Has the return message changed, maybe between different servers?

Comment: Strangely, no.  Copying and pasting the URL into a browser works fine. So I know the string is correct.  But passing it through the stringWithContentsOfUrl method fails, indicating that it is changing what is being passed or it is passing it in a different way, and I can't work out why

Comment: OK, I have fixed it by implementing NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection.  Means I have to restructure the way I am getting the content.  I was not getting any errors with the connection, but instead I was getting an error response from the server, kind of indicating that the username and password were wrong, but the output proves they were wrong (character encoding maybe?).

Interestingly this only appears to be a problem with this call, which is https and not http.  The rest of the calls which are http work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your user name is an e-mail address and has an at sign (@) in it, have you tried to escape the at sign in the URL by using %40 instead of @?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that loginDetails is nil, indicating an error retrieving the URL, rather than you actually receiving a "LOGIN ERROR" response.

Pass in an error object and log the error.

Comment: The server returns the string "LOGIN_ERROR" in case of failures, but the URL I am accessing is correct.  If I copy and paste the string from the log to a browser it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *loginDetails = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```